# How to remove invisible new line characters in Perl

Tags: shell, perl

I am writing a shell script in perl that takes values from two databases and compares them. When the script is finished it outputs a report that is supposed to be formatted this way:

Table Name   Date   value from Database 1   value from Database 2   Difference

The output is printed into a report file, but even when it is output to the command console it looks like this:

```
tablename    2017-06-20  7629628
 7629628
 0
```

Here's my code that makes the string then outputs it to the file:

```
$outputstring="$tablelist[0]    $DATErowcount0[$output_iteration]  $rowcount0[$output_iteration] $TDrowcount0[$output_iteration] $count_dif\n";
print FILE $outputstring;
```

There seems to be a newline character hidden after $rowcount0[$output_iteration] and before $count_dif. What do I need to do to fix this/print it all in one line?

To fill the arrays with values, values are read from files created by SQL commands.

Here's some of the code:

```
`$num_from_TDfile=substr $r2, 16;
$date_from_TDfile = substr $r2, 0, 12;
$TDrowcount0[$TDnum_rows0]=$num_from_TDfile;
$DATETDrowcount0[$TDnum_rows0]=$date_from_TDfile;
$TDnum_rows0=$TDnum_rows0+1;`
```

Comment: Having several unrelated arrays instead of an array of arrays makes this code pretty clunky. Think about how you're capturing this data. Some of your data needs the `chomp` treatment.

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include the code for populating `@tablelist` and the other arrays.

Comment: I'll try adding chomp statements for the arrays, thanks for the idea.

Comment: The arrays used for both databases are populated the same way as the code above

Answer (score -1):

Adding the `chomp` to each of the strings taken from the files as suggested by tadman fixed the output so that it was all on one line rather than three lines as in the question's example.